# If a specific folder exists then delete all the contents, else stop the script

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, directory

I need a script to find if a folder "c:\backup" really exists, delete all the folders contents BUT not delete the "backup" folder itself.

Need to be some "IF" function for security reasons to don´t get the risk for the script don´t find the folder (for any reason) and then start to delete all other folders in the system. So if the script don´t find the folder, the script has to abort the action.

Comment: What language you want? Have you tried any code? Post your code here. Don't ask us to write code for you. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for more info.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari I had tryed:  if exist "C:\backup\." rd /q /s "C:\backup\*" but it deletes the folder "backup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope it works... this is some VB code that may help you

```
   Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo("path")
    If dir.Exists Then
      Kill("path\*.*")
    Else
      ' Do whatever else
    End If
```

Comment: ill try to explain so you can get it working you have to replace the "path" with the actual path of where your backup is (its folder route) same goes for the "Kill()" just change the "path" text but leave the * . * since those are the files you want to delete (everything inside the folder)

Comment: Yes, I made that but is giving an error message: line 1, charater 9, Expected end of statement

Comment: in what language are you trying to get this working?

Comment: oh its a batch file then this wont work ill re-do the script in the language you need

Comment: I tryed to put the code into a vbs extension but didn't work. I had tryed also in .bat but didn't work too. Actually all the scripts that I use is in common .bat.